# getting kafka error : MetadataRequest versions older than 4 don't support the allowAutoTopicCreation field

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I developed spring-boot application using boot-version 2.1.3.RELEASE. Added kafka-client, spring-fafka, kafka_2.12 and kafka-streams dependencies without specific version. Application is intended to open stream from a kafka topic and do count aggregation by grouping on keys at timedwindow. While in debug mode, following error is logged.

> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnsupportedVersionException: MetadataRequest versions older than 4 don't support the allowAutoTopicCreation field
>
> 2019-10-18 09:18:05.050 DEBUG 6435 --- [0c5acc95c-admin] o.a.k.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient     : [AdminClient clientId=CAG__CNTS_service_ads_2-d1d85a17-42e5-4d98-9ef8-ed90c5acc95c-admin] Call(callName=topicsMetadata, deadlineMs=1571370604855) failed with non-retriable exception after 1 attempt(s)
>
> java.lang.Exception: UnsupportedVersionException: MetadataRequest versions older than 4 don't support the allowAutoTopicCreation field
>       at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient$Call.fail(KafkaAdminClient.java:612) ~[kafka-clients-2.0.1.jar:na]
>       at >org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient$AdminClientRunnable.handleResponses(KafkaAdminClient.java:984) [kafka-clients-2.0.1.jar:na]
>       at >org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient$AdminClientRunnable.run(KafkaAdminClient.java:1124) [kafka-clients-2.0.1.jar:na]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_172]

Comment: What is the Kafka version that you are using ?

Comment: kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0

Comment: Guys this is a three year old release and probably you are trying to use a newer client with a feature which is not supported on the Server. Would strongly recommend upgrading Kafka

Answer (score 2):

Boot 2.1.x (current is 2.1.9) uses spring-kafka 2.2.x and it uses the 2.0.1 kafka clients by default. See the [project page for the compatibility matrix](https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka). While you can generally use newer clients with older brokers (since 0.10), of course you can only use features that the broker supports.

0.10.x.x is simply too old for newer spring-kafka versions.