# Pyspark Structured Streaming - error related to allowAutoTopicCreation

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka

I'm trying to do some very basic stream processing using PySpark (3.2.4) Structured Streaming, using Kafka as my data source. Just to get up and running, I'm attempting the really basic task of parsing a field `changeType` from my source messages and appending it out to the console. However, when I run my script I get an `pyspark.errors.exceptions.captured.StreamingQueryException`. See below for script and traceback:

###### pyspark_structured_streaming.py

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StringType

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("PysparkTesting") \
    .getOrCreate()

spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel('WARN')

schema = StructType().add("changeType", StringType())

stream_data = spark \
    .readStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host1:port1,host2:port2") \
    .option("subscribe", "topic") \
    .load()


parsed_data = stream_data.selectExpr("CAST(value as STRING)") \
    .select(from_json("value", schema).alias("data")) \
    .select("data.changeType")

query = parsed_data.writeStream \
          .outputMode("append") \
          .format("console") \
          .start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

I run the script using the command

```
spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.4.1 pyspark_structured_streaming.py
```

which should run fine but gives the error:

###### Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/johnf/my_project/pyspark/pyspark_structured_streaming.py", line 31, in <module>
    query.awaitTermination()
  File "/Users/johnf/.conda/envs/my_project/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/streaming/query.py", line 201, in awaitTermination
  File "/Users/johnf/.conda/envs/my_project/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1322, in __call__
  File "/Users/johnf/.conda/envs/my_project/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/errors/exceptions/captured.py", line 175, in deco
pyspark.errors.exceptions.captured.StreamingQueryException: [STREAM_FAILED] Query [id = 290ef0e0-dca4-4a2a-b767-bd171210c2e4, runId = 61f00034-c12e-42a9-b55e-0ee133f8211a] terminated with exception: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnsupportedVersionException: MetadataRequest versions older than 4 don't support the allowAutoTopicCreation field
```

My first thought would be that this suggests the topic doesn't exist, hence an error about `allowAutoTopicCreation`. However, the topic definitely does exist and I can consume messages from it using `KafkaConsumer` from `kafka-python`.

In the same environment as Spark I also have [kafka-python](https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python) version 2.0.2 installed. The Kafka brokers I am trying to access are on remote servers in my company, Kafka version 2.6.0.3-8.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [getting kafka error : MetadataRequest versions older than 4 don't support the allowAutoTopicCreation field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58443784/getting-kafka-error-metadatarequest-versions-older-than-4-dont-support-the-al)

Comment: Your code doesn't include any Kafka library (Spark doesn't come with any). Please share how you've added it, and what version

Comment: @OneCricketeer, I've added some extra info in the edits.

Comment: @mazaneicha, while it does look related, I can't say for certain if it solves my problem and I don't see any obvious solutions from my POV as a Python/PySpark user

Comment: @OneCricketeer yep. Got confused by the last paragraph in John's question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> using PySpark (3.2.4)

Then you need to use version 3.2.4 of your kafka library

```
--packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.2.4
```

Answer (score -2):

`spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.4.1` indicates the Kafka 0.10.x client. You may want to try a newer version of the Kafka client for Spark. Look for a Kafka client package that's more aligned with Kafka 2.6.

Comment: That package is compiled against `kafka-clients:3.3.2` - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.13/3.4.1